# How to Disable sorting of only one specific column in Data tables?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Suppose i have the table like below :

> And I want to disable sorting of **Action Column**

```
<!--index.html-->      
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered post-list-table" id="table" >
  <thead>                      
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Created At</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

<!--Script.js-->
$('#table').DataTable();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery DataTables, sort by specific column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878098/jquery-datatables-sort-by-specific-column)

Comment: [Disable sorting on last column when using jQuery DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008545/disable-sorting-on-last-column-when-using-jquery-datatables)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Try adding :** [columns.orderable](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderable)

```
"columnDefs": [
    { "orderable": false, "targets": 2 }
  ]
```

[JSFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/g2remyvp/)

```js
<!--Script.js-->
$('#table').DataTable( {
"columnDefs": [
    { "orderable": false, "targets": 2 }
  ]
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered post-list-table" id="table" >
  <thead>                      
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Created At</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: OK !! Working Fine Now, Thanks For Your Effort

Comment: Apparently OP wanted to disable sorting on the last column, use `targets: -1` so that you don't have to hardcode the column number. [More info and full answer with an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008545/disable-sorting-on-last-column-when-using-jquery-datatables/12008678#12008678).

Answer (score 7):

Do this in jQuery

```
var table = $('#tbl').DataTable({
            "columnDefs": [{ targets: 'no-sort', orderable: false }]});
```

and add a class 'no-sort' to whatever headers you want to disable sort like this..

```
<th class="no-sort">Header n</th>
```

Answer (score 4):

Add a class to columns which you want to disable sort

```
<th class="no-sort">Operations</th>
```

then add the following style to your css

```
table.datatable thead th.no-sort {
    background: none;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('#table').dataTable({
    // display everything
    "iDisplayLength": -1,
    "aoColumns":[
        {"bSortable": true},
        {"bSortable": true},
        {"bSortable": false}
    ]
});
```

for reference - https://stackoverflow.com/a/7878609/1982631

Comment: Works great with legacy version of DataTables.

Answer (score 0):

If u want to disable sorting for all columns then u can do `$(th).unbind();` in footable